# Weird Like button behavior with different sites

Tags: networking, facebook-like

I'm trying to incorporate a like button in my site but it doesn't seem to appear. I've talked with another dev in the team and he sees it. We have a hunch it is a network problem BUT trying to diagnose it has gotten us weird results. Here are our results:

1. My local machine and any machine on my network

   - my site doesn't show like button
   - wired.com shows like button
   - techcrunch doesn't show like button
   - tried this for chrome, safari and ff. only safari shows the wired.com like button
   - i can access www.facebook.com
2. Other dev's machine and ipad(same network)

   - all sites show like button
3. remote rackspace windows server(just tried this out)

   - all sites show the fb button

Hunch: something to do with the firewall? But why can I access facebook directly? Why would they block the like button and not facebook itself? Also, why is wired.com's like button appearing and not on the other sites?

I am really stumped as to why this is happening and this is becoming a huge impediment. Thanks for any help/input!

P.S. I think we are getting a 403 from something. Sonicwall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I think we found it. Sonic wall or the network admin blocks anything with the word "proxy". It is weird though that wired.com's like button doesn't have that, but I think this is probably the reason why we're being blocked.